# Ksh script, copy files created after a specifc date

Tags: ksh, cp

I'm trying to do a little script to retrieve some files. 
What I've to do is to copy files from a reporty, but only files created for a specific date (ex : only files created on 11th November).

Do you have any idea how to perform this ?

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know if this will work in ksh, I've tried it in bash and zsh.

The difficult operation is to retrieve all files that, for example, changed today

```
find . -type f -newermt 2013-11-11 ! -newermt 2013-11-12 >list
```

...now you have a list, so you could iterate it and copy each entry wherever you want

```
while read file; do
  cp "$file" $destination
done <list
```

Comment: Actually, the files I want to create are in read-only, so it's not important to look if they changed today or not

Comment: You could then try `newerct` instead of `newermt`

Comment: Actually I've :

- find: invalid predicate `-newerct'
and
- find: invalid predicate `-newermt'

Comment: @user1058398: `-newermt` and `-newerct` are not in the POSIX standard, @Albero Zaccagni is probably referring to a GNU/Linux version (it has nothing to do with the shell).  Take a look at the `-mtime` and `-mmin` options instead.